# Entity with properties dependant on its generated ID

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa, entity

I want to persist an entity along with a cipher of its ID (primary key) which is going to be attributed by the database when the entity is first persisted. The way I did this was by persisting twice, a first time for having an ID assigned, having a `@PostPersist` callback that assigns the 'encryptedID' property and persisting a second time to update the 'encryptedID' field. My entity looks like this:

```
import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table(name = "encryptions")
public class EncryptionTest {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    long id;

    String encryptedID;

    @PostPersist
    void updateEncryptedID(){
        this.encryptedID = encrypt(id);
    }

    private String encrypt(long idToEncrypt){
        return "encrypted_" + idToEncrypt ;
    }
}
```

Is there a better way to do this though, without having to persist twice?

Comment: Hello, please show us the service that does the persist.

Comment: I am just using hibernate's session factory to get a session and then session.saveOrUpdate(new EncryptionTest())